# What are Kernel PMU event-s in perf_events list?

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring, cpu, perf-event

Searching for *what* one can monitor with `perf_events` on Linux, I cannot find what `Kernel PMU event` are?
Namely, with `perf version 3.13.11-ckt39` the `perf list` shows events like:

```
branch-instructions OR cpu/branch-instructions/    [Kernel PMU event]
```

Overall there are:

```
Tracepoint event
Software event
Hardware event
Hardware cache event
Raw hardware event descriptor
Hardware breakpoint
Kernel PMU event
```

and I would like to understand what they are, where they come from. I have some kind of explanation for all, but `Kernel PMU event` item.

From [perf wiki tutorial](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Events) and [Brendan Gregg's page](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#Events) I get that:

- `Tracepoints` are the clearest -- these are macros on the kernel source, which make a probe point for monitoring, they were introduced with `ftrace` project and now are used by everybody
- `Software` are kernel's low level counters and some internal data-structures (hence, they are different from tracepoints)
- `Hardware event` are some very basic CPU events, found on *all* architectures and somehow easily accessed by kernel
- `Hardware cache event` are nicknames to `Raw hardware event descriptor` -- it works as follows

  as I got it, `Raw hardware event descriptor` are more (micro?)architecture-specific events than `Hardware event`, the events come from Processor Monitoring Unit (PMU) or other specific features of a given processor, thus they are available only on some micro-architectures (let's say "architecture" means "x86_64" and all the rest of the implementation details are "micro-architecture");
  and they are accessible for instrumentation via these strange descriptors

  ```
  rNNN                                               [Raw hardware event descriptor]
  cpu/t1=v1[,t2=v2,t3 ...]/modifier                  [Raw hardware event descriptor]
   (see 'man perf-list' on how to encode it)
  ```

  -- these descriptors, which events they point to and so on is to be found in processor's manuals ([PMU events in perf wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Hardware_events));

  but then, when people know that there is some useful event on a given processor they give it a nickname and plug it into linux as `Hardware cache event` for ease of access

  -- correct me if I'm wrong (strangely all `Hardware cache event` are about `something-loads` or `something-misses` -- very like the actual processor's cache..)
- now, the `Hardware breakpoint`

  ```
  mem:<addr>[:access]                                [Hardware breakpoint]
  ```

  is a hardware feature, which is probably common to most modern architectures, and works as a breakpoint in a debugger? (probably it is googlable anyway)
- finally, `Kernel PMU event` I don't manage to google on;

  it also doesn't show up in [the listing of Events in Brendan's perf
  page](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#Events), so it's new?

  Maybe it's just nicknames to hardware events specifically from PMU? (For ease of access it got a separate section in the list of events in addition to the nickname.)
  In fact, maybe `Hardware cache events` are nicknames to hardware events from CPU's cache and `Kernel PMU event` are nicknames to PMU events? (Why not call it `Hardware PMU event` then?..)
  It could be just new naming scheme -- the nicknames to hardware events got sectionized?

  And these events refer to things like `cpu/mem-stores/`, plus since some linux version events got descriptions in `/sys/devices/` and:

  ```
  # find /sys/ -type d -name events
  /sys/devices/cpu/events
  /sys/devices/uncore_cbox_0/events
  /sys/devices/uncore_cbox_1/events
  /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events
  ```

  -- `debug/tracing` is for `ftrace` and tracepoints, other directories match exactly what `perf list` shows as `Kernel PMU event`.

Could someone point me to a good explanation/documentation of what `Kernel PMU events` or `/sys/..events/` systems are?
Also, is `/sys/..events/` some new effort to systemize hardware events or something alike? (Then, Kernel PMU is like "the Performance Monitoring Unit of Kernel".)

## PS

To give better context, not-privileged run of `perf list` (tracepoints are not shown, but all 1374 of them are there) with full listings of `Kernel PMU event`s and `Hardware cache event`s and others skipped:

```
$ perf list 

List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e):
 cpu-cycles OR cycles                               [Hardware event]
 instructions                                       [Hardware event]
 ...
 cpu-clock                                          [Software event]
 task-clock                                         [Software event]
 ...
 L1-dcache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
 L1-dcache-store-misses                             [Hardware cache event]
 L1-dcache-prefetch-misses                          [Hardware cache event]
 L1-icache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
 LLC-loads                                          [Hardware cache event]
 LLC-stores                                         [Hardware cache event]
 LLC-prefetches                                     [Hardware cache event]
 dTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
 dTLB-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
 iTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
 iTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
 branch-loads                                       [Hardware cache event]
 branch-load-misses                                 [Hardware cache event]

 branch-instructions OR cpu/branch-instructions/    [Kernel PMU event]
 branch-misses OR cpu/branch-misses/                [Kernel PMU event]
 bus-cycles OR cpu/bus-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
 cache-misses OR cpu/cache-misses/                  [Kernel PMU event]
 cache-references OR cpu/cache-references/          [Kernel PMU event]
 cpu-cycles OR cpu/cpu-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
 instructions OR cpu/instructions/                  [Kernel PMU event]
 mem-loads OR cpu/mem-loads/                        [Kernel PMU event]
 mem-stores OR cpu/mem-stores/                      [Kernel PMU event]
 ref-cycles OR cpu/ref-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
 stalled-cycles-frontend OR cpu/stalled-cycles-frontend/ [Kernel PMU event]
 uncore_cbox_0/clockticks/                          [Kernel PMU event]
 uncore_cbox_1/clockticks/                          [Kernel PMU event]

 rNNN                                               [Raw hardware event descriptor]
 cpu/t1=v1[,t2=v2,t3 ...]/modifier                  [Raw hardware event descriptor]
  (see 'man perf-list' on how to encode it)

 mem:<addr>[:access]                                [Hardware breakpoint]

 [ Tracepoints not available: Permission denied ]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Googling and `ack`-ing is over! I've got some answer.

But firstly let me clarify the aim of the question a little more:
I want clearly distinguish independent processes in the system and their performance counters. For instance, a core of a processor, an uncore device (learned about it recently), kernel or user application on the processor, a bus (= bus controller), a hard drive are all independent processes, they are not synchronized by a clock. And nowadays probably all of them have some Process Monitoring Counter (PMC). I'd like to understand which processes the counters come from. (It is also helpful in googling: the "vendor" of a thing zeros it better.)

Also, the gear used for the search: `Ubuntu 14.04`, `linux 3.13.0-103-generic`, processor `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3317U CPU @ 1.70GHz` (from `/proc/cpuinfo`, it has 2 physical cores and 4 virtual -- the physical matter here).

## Terminology, things the question involves

From Intel:

- [processor is a `core` device (it's 1 device/process) and a bunch of `uncore` devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncore), `core` is what runs the program (clock, ALU, registers etc), `uncore` are devices put on die, close to the processor for speed and low latency (the real reason is "because the manufacturer can do it"); as I understood it is basically the Northbridge, like on PC motherboard, plus caches; and AMD actually calls these devices NorthBridge`instead of`uncore`;
- `ubox` which shows up in my `sysfs`

  ```
  $ find /sys/devices/ -type d -name events 
  /sys/devices/cpu/events
  /sys/devices/uncore_cbox_0/events
  /sys/devices/uncore_cbox_1/events
  ```

  -- is an `uncore` device, which manages Last Level Cache (LLC, the last one before hitting RAM); I have 2 cores, thus 2 LLC and 2 `ubox`;
- Processor Monitoring Unit (PMU) is a separate device which monitors operations of a processor and records them in Processor Monitoring Counter (PMC) (counts cache misses, processor cycles etc); they exist on `core` and `uncore` devices; the `core` ones are accessed with `rdpmc` (read PMC) instruction; the `uncore`, since these devices depend on actual processor at hand, are accessed via Model Specific Registers (MSR) via `rdmsr` (naturally);

  apparently, the workflow with them is done via pairs of registers -- 1 register sets which events the counter counts, 2 register is the value in the counter; the counter can be configured to increment after a bunch of events, not just 1; + there are some interupts/tech noticing overflows in these counters;
- more one can find in Intel's "IA-32 Software Developer's Manual Vol 3B" chapter 18 "PERFORMANCE MONITORING";

  also, the MSR's format concretely for these `uncore` PMCs for version "Architectural Performance Monitoring Version 1" (there are versions 1-4 in the manual, I don't know which one is my processor)  is described in "Figure 18-1. Layout of IA32_PERFEVTSELx MSRs" (page 18-3 in mine), and section "18.2.1.2 Pre-defined Architectural Performance Events" with "Table 18-1. UMask and Event Select Encodings for Pre-Defined Architectural Performance Events", which shows the events which show up as `Hardware event` in `perf list`.

From linux kernel:

- kernel has a system (abstraction/layer) for managing performance counters of different origin, both software (kernel's) and hardware, it is described in `linux-source-3.13.0/tools/perf/design.txt`; an event in this system is defined as `struct perf_event_attr` (file `linux-source-3.13.0/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h`), the main part of which is probably `__u64 config` field -- it  can hold both a CPU-specific  event definition (the 64bit word in the format described on those Intel's figures) or a kernel's event

  > The MSB of the config word signifies if the rest contains [raw CPU's or kernel's event]

  the kernel's event defined with 7 bits for type and 56 for event's identifier, which are `enum`-s in the code, which in my case are:

  ```
  $ ak PERF_TYPE linux-source-3.13.0/include/
  ...
  linux-source-3.13.0/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h
  29: PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE      = 0,
  30: PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE      = 1,
  31: PERF_TYPE_TRACEPOINT    = 2,
  32: PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE      = 3,
  33: PERF_TYPE_RAW           = 4,
  34: PERF_TYPE_BREAKPOINT    = 5,
  36: PERF_TYPE_MAX,         /* non-ABI */
  ```

  (`ak` is my alias to `ack-grep`, which is the name for `ack` on Debian; and `ack` is awesome);

  in the source code of kernel one can see operations like "register all PMUs dicovered on the system" and structure types `struct pmu`, which are passed to something like `int perf_pmu_register(struct pmu *pmu, const char *name, int type)` -- thus, one could just call this system "kernel's PMU", which would be an aggregation of all PMUs on the system; but this name could be interpreted as monitoring system of kernel's operations, which would be misleading;

  let's call this subsystem `perf_events` for clarity;
- as any kernel subsystem, this subsystem can be exported into `sysfs` (which is made to export kernel subsystems for people to use); and that's what are those `events` directories in my `/sys/` -- the exported (parts of?) `perf_events` subsystem;
- also, the user-space utility `perf` (built into linux) is still a separate program and has its' own abstractions; it represents an event requested for monitoring by user as `perf_evsel` (files `linux-source-3.13.0/tools/perf/util/evsel.{h,c}`) -- this structure has a field `struct perf_event_attr attr;`, but also a field like `struct cpu_map *cpus;` that's how `perf` utility assigns an event to all or particular CPUs.

## Answer

1. Indeed, `Hardware cache event` are "shortcuts" to the events of the cache devices (`ubox` of Intel's `uncore` devices), which are processor-specific, and can be accessed via the protocol `Raw hardware event descriptor`. And `Hardware event` are more stable within architecture, which, as I understand, name the events from the `core` device. There no other "shortcuts" in my kernel `3.13` to some other `uncore` events and counters. All the rest -- `Software` and `Tracepoints` -- are kernel's events.

   I wonder if the `core`'s `Hardware event`s are accessed via the same `Raw hardware event descriptor` protocol. They might not -- since the counter/PMU sits on `core`, maybe it is accessed differently. For instance, with that `rdpmu` instruction, instead of `rdmsr`, which accesses `uncore`. But it is not that important.
2. `Kernel PMU event` are just the events, which are exported into `sysfs`. I don't know how this is done (automatically by kernel all discovered PMCs on the system, or just something hard-coded, and if I add a `kprobe` -- is it exported? etc). But the main point is that these are the same events as `Hardware event` or any other in the internal `perf_event` system.

   And I don't know what those

   ```
   $ ls /sys/devices/uncore_cbox_0/events
   clockticks
   ```

   are.

## Details on `Kernel PMU event`

Searching through the code leads to:

```
$ ak "Kernel PMU" linux-source-3.13.0/tools/perf/
linux-source-3.13.0/tools/perf/util/pmu.c                                                            
629:                printf("  %-50s [Kernel PMU event]\n", aliases[j]);
```

-- which happens in the function

```
void print_pmu_events(const char *event_glob, bool name_only) {
   ...
        while ((pmu = perf_pmu__scan(pmu)) != NULL)
                list_for_each_entry(alias, &pmu->aliases, list) {...}
   ... 
   /* b.t.w. list_for_each_entry is an iterator
    * apparently, it takes a block of {code} and runs over some lost
    * Ruby built in kernel!
    */
    // then there is a loop over these aliases and
    loop{ ... printf("  %-50s [Kernel PMU event]\n", aliases[j]); ... }
}
```

and `perf_pmu__scan` is in the same file:

```
struct perf_pmu *perf_pmu__scan(struct perf_pmu *pmu) {
    ...
                pmu_read_sysfs(); // that's what it calls
}
```

-- which is also in the same file:

```
/* Add all pmus in sysfs to pmu list: */
static void pmu_read_sysfs(void) {...}
```

That's it.

## Details on `Hardware event` and `Hardware cache event`

Apparently, the `Hardware event` come from what Intel calls "Pre-defined Architectural Performance Events", 18.2.1.2 in IA-32 Software Developer's Manual Vol 3B. And "18.1 PERFORMANCE MONITORING OVERVIEW" of the manual describes them as:

> The second class of performance monitoring capabilities is referred to as architectural performance monitoring.
>   This class supports the same counting and Interrupt-based event sampling usages, with a smaller set of available
>   events.
>   The visible behavior of architectural performance events is consistent across processor implementations.
>   Availability of architectural performance monitoring capabilities is enumerated using the CPUID.0AH. These events are discussed in Section 18.2.

-- the other type is:

> Starting with Intel Core Solo and Intel Core Duo processors, there are two classes of performance monitoring capa-bilities.
>   The first class supports events for monitoring performance using counting or interrupt-based event sampling usage.
>   These events are non-architectural and vary from one processor model to another...

And these events are indeed just links to underlying "raw" hardware events, which can be accessed via `perf` utility as `Raw hardware event descriptor`.

To check this one looks at `linux-source-3.13.0/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event_intel.c`:

```
/*
 * Intel PerfMon, used on Core and later.
 */
static u64 intel_perfmon_event_map[PERF_COUNT_HW_MAX] __read_mostly =
{
    [PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES]              = 0x003c,
    [PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS]            = 0x00c0,
    [PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_REFERENCES]        = 0x4f2e,
    [PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES]            = 0x412e,
    ...
}
```

-- and exactly `0x412e` is found in "Table 18-1. UMask and Event Select Encodings for Pre-Defined Architectural Performance Events" for "LLC Misses":

```
Bit Position CPUID.AH.EBX | Event Name | UMask | Event Select
...
                        4 | LLC Misses | 41H   | 2EH
```

-- `H` is for hex. All 7 are in the structure, plus `[PERF_COUNT_HW_REF_CPU_CYCLES] = 0x0300, /* pseudo-encoding *`. (The naming is a bit different, addresses are the same.)

Then the `Hardware cache event`s are in structures like (in the same file):

```
static __initconst const u64 snb_hw_cache_extra_regs
                            [PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MAX]
                            [PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_MAX]
                            [PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MAX] =
{...}
```

-- which should be for sandy bridge?

One of these -- `snb_hw_cache_extra_regs[LL][OP_WRITE][RESULT_ACCESS]` is filled with `SNB_DMND_WRITE|SNB_L3_ACCESS`, where from the def-s above:

```
#define SNB_L3_ACCESS           SNB_RESP_ANY
#define SNB_RESP_ANY            (1ULL << 16)                                                                            
#define SNB_DMND_WRITE          (SNB_DMND_RFO|SNB_LLC_RFO)
#define SNB_DMND_RFO            (1ULL << 1)
#define SNB_LLC_RFO             (1ULL << 8)
```

which should equal to `0x00010102`, but I don't know how to check it with some table.

And this gives an idea how it is used in `perf_events`:

```
$ ak hw_cache_extra_regs linux-source-3.13.0/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/
linux-source-3.13.0/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event.c
50:u64 __read_mostly hw_cache_extra_regs
292:    attr->config1 = hw_cache_extra_regs[cache_type][cache_op][cache_result];

linux-source-3.13.0/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event.h
521:extern u64 __read_mostly hw_cache_extra_regs

linux-source-3.13.0/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event_intel.c
272:static __initconst const u64 snb_hw_cache_extra_regs
567:static __initconst const u64 nehalem_hw_cache_extra_regs
915:static __initconst const u64 slm_hw_cache_extra_regs
2364:       memcpy(hw_cache_extra_regs, nehalem_hw_cache_extra_regs,
2365:              sizeof(hw_cache_extra_regs));
2407:       memcpy(hw_cache_extra_regs, slm_hw_cache_extra_regs,
2408:              sizeof(hw_cache_extra_regs));
2424:       memcpy(hw_cache_extra_regs, nehalem_hw_cache_extra_regs,
2425:              sizeof(hw_cache_extra_regs));
2452:       memcpy(hw_cache_extra_regs, snb_hw_cache_extra_regs,
2453:              sizeof(hw_cache_extra_regs));
2483:       memcpy(hw_cache_extra_regs, snb_hw_cache_extra_regs,
2484:              sizeof(hw_cache_extra_regs));
2516:       memcpy(hw_cache_extra_regs, snb_hw_cache_extra_regs, sizeof(hw_cache_extra_regs));
$
```

The `memcpy`s are done in `__init int intel_pmu_init(void) {... case:...}`.

Only `attr->config1` is a bit odd. But it is there, in `perf_event_attr` (same `linux-source-3.13.0/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h` file):

```
...
    union {
            __u64           bp_addr;
            __u64           config1; /* extension of config */                                                      
    };
    union {
            __u64           bp_len;
            __u64           config2; /* extension of config1 */
    };
...
```

They are registered in kernel's `perf_events` system with calls to `int perf_pmu_register(struct pmu *pmu, const char *name, int type)` (defined in `linux-source-3.13.0/kernel/events/core.c:` ):

- `static int __init init_hw_perf_events(void)` (file `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event.c`) with call `perf_pmu_register(&pmu, "cpu", PERF_TYPE_RAW);`
- `static int __init uncore_pmu_register(struct intel_uncore_pmu *pmu)` (file `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event_intel_uncore.c`, there are also `arch/x86/kernel/cpu/perf_event_amd_uncore.c`) with call `ret = perf_pmu_register(&pmu->pmu, pmu->name, -1);`

So finally, all events come from hardware and everything is ok. But here one could notice: why do we have `LLC-loads` in `perf list` and not `ubox1 LLC-loads`, since these are HW events and they actualy come from `ubox`es?

That's a thing of the `perf` utility and its' `perf_evsel` structure: when you request a HW event from `perf` you define the event which processors you want it from (default is all), and it sets up the `perf_evsel` with the requested event and processors, then at aggregation is sums the counters from all processors in `perf_evsel` (or does some other statistics with them).

One can see it in `tools/perf/builtin-stat.c`:

```
/*
 * Read out the results of a single counter:
 * aggregate counts across CPUs in system-wide mode
 */
static int read_counter_aggr(struct perf_evsel *counter)
{
    struct perf_stat *ps = counter->priv;
    u64 *count = counter->counts->aggr.values;
    int i;

    if (__perf_evsel__read(counter, perf_evsel__nr_cpus(counter),
                           thread_map__nr(evsel_list->threads), scale) < 0)
            return -1;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            update_stats(&ps->res_stats[i], count[i]);

    if (verbose) {
            fprintf(output, "%s: %" PRIu64 " %" PRIu64 " %" PRIu64 "\n",
                    perf_evsel__name(counter), count[0], count[1], count[2]);
    }

    /*
     * Save the full runtime - to allow normalization during printout:
     */
    update_shadow_stats(counter, count);

    return 0;
}
```

(So, for the utility `perf` a "single counter" is not even a `perf_event_attr`, which is a general form, fitting both SW and HW events, it is an event of your query -- the same events may come from different devices and they are aggregated.)

Also a notice: `struct perf_evsel` contains only 1 `struct perf_evevent_attr`, but it also has a field `struct perf_evsel *leader;` -- it is nested.
There is a feature of "(hierarchical) groups of events" in `perf_events`, when you can dispatch a bunch of counters together, so that they can be compared to each other and so on. Not sure how it works with independent events from `kernel`, `core`, `ubox`. But this nesting of `perf_evsel` is it. And, most likely, that's how `perf` manages a query of several events together.

Comment: What an answer! You've really hit out of the park there!