# How could I add support for an event modifier in perf

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, power-management, perf

I need to account power for the kernel space, but unfortunately the k modifier are not supported for the power/energy-cores/. I have an example of what I'm trying to do below.

I'm reading the source of perf and the structure of the Kernel PMU Events, but I'm a bit lost. Is there someone familiar with the source code of perf who could share some tips of how these modifiers works in the source?

```
 user@dkphome:~$ sudo perf stat -a -e power/energy-cores/k -I 1000 sleep 5
 #           time             counts unit events
 1.000099515    <not supported> Joules power/energy-cores/k                                        
 2.000246523    <not supported> Joules power/energy-cores/k                                        
 3.000440743    <not supported> Joules power/energy-cores/k                                        
 4.000673143    <not supported> Joules power/energy-cores/k                                        
 5.000722624    <not supported> Joules power/energy-cores/k                                        
 user@dkphome:~$ sudo perf stat -a -e power/energy-cores/ -I 1000 sleep 5
 #           time             counts   unit events
 1.000128209               0,19 Joules power/energy-cores/                                         
 2.000257170               0,25 Joules power/energy-cores/                                         
 3.000406715               0,26 Joules power/energy-cores/                                         
 4.000571140               0,20 Joules power/energy-cores/                                         
 5.000711815               1,01 Joules power/energy-cores/                                         
 5.000882867               0,00 Joules power/energy-cores/
```

PS: This other question was a lot of help [What are Kernel PMU event-s in perf_events list?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326621/what-are-kernel-pmu-event-s-in-perf-events-list)