# PMU and tracepoints

Tags: performance, monitoring, cpu, ftrace

I am searching for information about the mechanism of creation of tracepoints. From this topic [What are Kernel PMU event-s in perf_events list?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326621/what-are-kernel-pmu-event-s-in-perf-events-list) and this blog [brendangregg](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/index.html) I've got that tracepoints are some macros inside the kernel code which are called when they are enabled, but I'm a little bit confused how tracepoint connected with PMU (because it mentioned in both links)?